# Since upgrading to Windows 8.1, I can't open any files on a SMB share shared by my OS X Mavericks Mac

Tags: macos, networking, mac, network-shares, samba

I have a PC with Windows 8.1 and a Mac with Mavericks. I have a folder on the Mac that is shared with the PC. When I'm on the PC and I try to open a file that is shared by the Mac, such as an ISO file (a disk image), then I get a message saying that I cannot open the file, or the file is in use (it depends on the app/filetype). I have the same problem when I open a video file. Strangely, text files and PDF files are just fine. And if I copy any of the problematic files to the local Windows disk, then I can open them just fine.

The specific error messages are:

- AVI files opened in VLC: "Your input can't be opened. VLC is unable to open the MRL."
- ISO files opened by Windows Explorer: "Sorry, there was a problem mounting the file."

This only started happening after I upgraded to Windows 8.1 on the PC and Mavericks on the Mac. Mavericks upgraded its SMB version from SMB1 to SMB2, so perhaps that is related?
Does anyone know what the problem might be, and how I could fix it?

Comment: It looks like Debra's answer is correct. If its not, can you point out the problems with it? Related: [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).

Answer (score 1):

A Windows 8.1 update broke some SMB functionality;  a fix is expected in November, per http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2883200

This assumes that you didn't knowingly disable SMB2.0/3.0.